# Atributo required no me funciona con código php

Tags: php

Tengo esta parte de código en php de un formulario. El formulario lo recibo correctamente, sin embargo el atributo required no surte efecto, por lo que si se envia el formulario sin seleccionar alguna option no aparece el mensaje de rellenar campo obligatorio, por lo que ese campo llega vacío en la recepción del formulario. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para el select del formulario sea obligatorio?

```
    {
echo "<select name='time' required>";
 echo  "<option disabled selected>Reservar día y hora</option>";
echo   "<optgroup label='18/1'>";
echo   "<option value='8:00-9:00'>08:00 - 9:00</option>";
 echo    "<option value='9:15-10:15'>9:15 - 10:15</option>";
 echo    "<option value='10:30-11:30'>10:30 - 11:30</option>";
 echo    "<option value='11:45-12:45'>11:45 - 12:45</option>";
 echo    "<option value='13:00-14:00'>13:00 - 14:00</option>";
echo     "<option value='14:15-15:15'>14:15 - 15:15</option>";
echo     "<option value='15:30-16:30'>15:30 - 16:30</option>";
echo     "<option value='16:45-17:45'>16:45 - 17:45</option>";
echo    "<option value='18:00-19:00' disabled>18:00 - 19:00</option>";
echo     "<option value='19:15-20:15'>19:15 - 20:15</option>";
echo     "<option value='20:30-21:30'>20:30 - 21:30</option>";
echo   "</optgroup>";
echo   "</select>";
}
```

El código resuelto es este

```
    {
echo "<select name='time' required>";
echo "<option value=''>Reservar hora</option>";
echo   "<optgroup label='18/1'>";
echo   "<option value='8:00-9:00'>08:00 - 9:00</option>";
 echo    "<option value='9:15-10:15'>9:15 - 10:15</option>";
 echo    "<option value='10:30-11:30'>10:30 - 11:30</option>";
 echo    "<option value='11:45-12:45'>11:45 - 12:45</option>";
 echo    "<option value='13:00-14:00'>13:00 - 14:00</option>";
echo     "<option value='14:15-15:15'>14:15 - 15:15</option>";
echo     "<option value='15:30-16:30'>15:30 - 16:30</option>";
echo     "<option value='16:45-17:45'>16:45 - 17:45</option>";
echo    "<option value='18:00-19:00' disabled>18:00 - 19:00</option>";
echo     "<option value='19:15-20:15'>19:15 - 20:15</option>";
echo     "<option value='20:30-21:30'>20:30 - 21:30</option>";
echo   "</optgroup>";
echo   "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Tú tienes por defecto un `option` seleccionado: `<option disabled selected>Reservar día y hora</option>` de modo que la restricción `required` queda satisfecha. ¿Por qué llega vacío? Porque ese `option` no tiene ningún `value`, prueba a ponerle uno y verás que recibe ese dato, por ejemplo: `<option value='00:00' disabled selected>Reservar día y hora</option>`

Comment: Con el valor -1 no me ha funcionado. Al final he encontrado la solución le he añadido un value vacio con comillas simples , ahora lo pongo en el código. Muchas gracias

Comment: Nop, lo que marca la diferencia en tu nuevo código es que **ya no tiene el `selected`**. Si pones el `selected` volverá a pasar lo de antes por lo ya dicho, se asume que tienes un `option` seleccionado al enviar el formulario.

Answer (score 1):

Los `select` siempre han tenido ese problemita, voy a ver si ayudo en algo.

@A.Cedano según la documentación

> If a select element has a required attribute specified, does not have a multiple attribute specified, and has a display size of 1; and if the value of the first option element in the select element's list of options (if any) is the empty string, and that option element's parent node is the select element (and not an optgroup element), then that option is the select element's placeholder label option.

Esto se podría traducir en cristiano como

> Se puede usar el atributo `required` de HTML5 en un `<select>` si le da al `<option>` predeterminado un atributo de valor vacío (**value=""**) entre otros criterios del `<select>`.

Para el ejemplo, la mejor manera de llegar a tener lo que el OP quiere sería con algo como:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
            <select name='time' required="required">
                <option disabled selected value="">Select an option</option>                
                <optgroup label='18/1'>
                    <option value='8:00-9:00'>08:00 - 9:00</option>
                    <option value='9:15-10:15'>9:15 - 10:15</option>
                    <option value='10:30-11:30'>10:30 - 11:30</option>
                    <option value='11:45-12:45'>11:45 - 12:45</option>
                    <option value='13:00-14:00'>13:00 - 14:00</option>
                    <option value='14:15-15:15'>14:15 - 15:15</option>
                    <option value='15:30-16:30'>15:30 - 16:30</option>
                    <option value='16:45-17:45'>16:45 - 17:45</option>
                    <option value='18:00-19:00' disabled>18:00 - 19:00</option>
                    <option value='19:15-20:15'>19:15 - 20:15</option>
                    <option value='20:30-21:30'>20:30 - 21:30</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

En primer lugar, a pesar de usar **selected** para obviamente seleccionar la opción que **YO** quiero, esta no se envía porque su `value` está vacío: **value=""**

Algo bonito de este `<select>` es que aunque en el combo aparece la mencionada opción (**Select an option**) como esta esta `disabled` no se puede seleccionar.

En mi caso particular yo  prefiero esconder del combo ese **Select an option** con `hidden`

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
            <select name='time' required="required">
                <option hidden selected value="">Select an option</option>
                <optgroup label='18/1'>
                    <option value='8:00-9:00'>08:00 - 9:00</option>
                    <option value='9:15-10:15'>9:15 - 10:15</option>
                    <option value='10:30-11:30'>10:30 - 11:30</option>
                    <option value='11:45-12:45'>11:45 - 12:45</option>
                    <option value='13:00-14:00'>13:00 - 14:00</option>
                    <option value='14:15-15:15'>14:15 - 15:15</option>
                    <option value='15:30-16:30'>15:30 - 16:30</option>
                    <option value='16:45-17:45'>16:45 - 17:45</option>
                    <option value='18:00-19:00' disabled>18:00 - 19:00</option>
                    <option value='19:15-20:15'>19:15 - 20:15</option>
                    <option value='20:30-21:30'>20:30 - 21:30</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
```

En teoría, esa es la "nueva onda", ocultar la opción default, a mi me gusta más pero es solo cuestión de gustos.

**Recomendaciones Importantes**: Por favor dejen de "imprimir" condigo HTML con PHP, eso es mala practica y un desorden horrible, hasta me han llorado los ojos. Acaso no se ve mejor como yo lo he puesto en los Snippets??

Y, para mayor validación, usar los tributos de HTML5 no es suficiente, esto se tendría que re-validar con el lenguaje procesador (para el caso PHP).

Comment: Sobre comentario de OCHOA: **Recomendaciones Importantes: Por favor dejen de "imprimir" condigo HTML con PHP**
Lo he puesto asi, porque ese código esta dentro de la función de fecha de los días de la semana, de manera que cada día se van desactivando las horas reservadas. Yo lo he puesto así y me fuciona para que lo quiero. Quizás haya alguna otra manera mejor de hacerlo, pero a mi así me vale ahora mismo.

Comment: Es que funcionar pueda que funcione, pero siempre se puede hacer de la manera correcta, no necesitas imprimir el HTML con PHP solo sus valores, pero en fin es solo una recomendación nada más...